# VPN client based web browser for Android to cross over all STUN/TURN/ICE/NAT issues and have a freedom of multimedia

Tags: networking, vpn, voip, firewall, openvpn

Its too hard to first build one apps and then its nightmare to make the network work. Is it not possible in Android Mobile/Tablet and all Chrome browsers default to have VPN Client embedded? So that we can do interconnection between:

OpenSWAN server in the cloud with IPSec host to host? Using mobile apps or javascript initialize it for example:

```
var ipsec = "
conn test
    type=tunnel
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    # Lifetime: 1440 sec
    ike=aes128-md5;modp1024!
    # Lifetime: 3600 sec
    phase2alg=aes128-md5;modp1024
    aggrmode=no    
    left=xxxx
    leftsubnet=10.109.0.0/24
    right=10.0.0.108
    rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
    #auto=start
"
android.vpn.tunnel(ipsec);
```

EDIT:

How to use the systems VPN from apps or web browsers to make with my VPN server interconnection by using javascript or java code triggering?

- avoid using STUN/UPnP/TURN/ICE/NAT and simply jump to VPN IPSec host to host

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AlEverett: I have an apps which send and receive rtp/sip/h.323 multi-media packets for P2P + it has file transfering protocol, but behind triple nat or behind many nat it fails to interconnect with peer2. So i need to have on the fly VPN client in the web browser or Android library which allow me to do that. Is there any way to make VPN client active using javascript from browser or java apps ?

Comment: Okay. Can you _[edit] your question_ to include that vital information?